# Django-Registration: Overriding the default fields

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-registration

Yesterday I faced a problem trying to override the RegistrationForm of Django-Registration app. The class `RegistrationForm` inherit from `UserCreationForm` of [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/#UserCreationForm), which is based on `ModelForm`, so I created my custom class inheriting from `RegistrationForm` in this way:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'hasdsa', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'hasdsa', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'hasdsa', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'hasdsa', 'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

I set the Meta class in this way because the model `User` and the fields `username, email, password1, password2` are the same attribute of `UserCreationForm`. This code live in a module named **accounts / forms.py** and is called directly from **accounts / urls.py** in this way:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from registration.backends.hmac import views

from accounts.forms import MyRegistrationForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=MyRegistrationForm), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
]
```

The goal here is overriding the attributes of an input field of a form with widgets adding attributes like `class` or `placeholder` or change the `labels` of the form or adding `error_messages` and so on.

As explained in Django-Registration [docs](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/custom-user.html#overview) to achieve this you just need to pass your custom form to `form_class` parameter of the `RegistrationView`. **Done**. It doesn't works and I don't know why.

[image: registration_form.html - context analysis]

As you see in the screenshot, DDT (Django Debug Toolbar) reports the fields of the form and all data available from there. The output of `{{ form.as_p }}` tag return this result:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='dNeT0R1JPIBtsrGCbcyPQjPLDAW7P7qb' />
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input class="form-control" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="hasdsa" type="text" /> <span class="helptext">Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span></p>
    <p><label for="id_email">Email:</label> <input id="id_email" name="email" type="email" /> <span class="helptext">email address</span></p>
    <p><label for="id_password1">Password:</label> <input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_password2">Password confirmation:</label> <input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" /> <span class="helptext">Enter the same password as before, for verification.</span></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And the bug come from there. As you can see, only the `username` field is changed. You can see the attribute `class` and `placeholder` overrided in the widget. But all other fields are still the same. Just a question: **Why**?

Instead to set the model and fields attributes of the meta class in the way reported above, I tried with:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        widgets = { ... }
```

We don't need to change those attributes, we are only interested on widgets, but the result is the same, it doesn't works.

I'd also like to know what is the best way to change the widgets of all forms in a project. Overriding each form in this way? Using a template tag and filter each form field? Using a middleware? If you use a framework like bootstrap, probably you want to have the attribute `class="form-control"` for each input field. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.Field(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    email = forms.Field(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.Field(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.Field(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

class Meta:
    model = User    
    fields = ('username','email','password1',)
```

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm): 
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form- 
                                                       control-user',
                                             "placeholder": "First Name"}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form- 
                                 control-user', "placeholder": "Last Name"}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', "placeholder": "Email"}),

        }
```