# I want to customize django.contrib.auth.views.login form

Tags: python, django

I have a template and css with it.

```
    <form class="form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" value="Login" id="login-button">Login</button>
    </form>
```

I know that I have to add    {{ form.username }} and   {{ form.password }}
but How can I add a placeholder to fields?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523286/how-to-add-placeholder-to-forms-of-django-registration

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the form and change the widget attributes.

```
class MyLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.placeholder = 'Username'
        self.fields['password'].widget.placeholder = 'Password'
```